# Entering the UK as a tourist then as a student

Tags: visas, uk

I’m an American student looking to visit my family in the UK this summer prior to starting my course in September. My course is less than 6 months so I do no need a student visa, simply just enter with my student documents a week before my course begins. My question is if I could visit my family for the summer (approximately 2.5 months) on a tourist visa, which grants me a 6 month stay. I would leave the UK for approximately a month to visit some other family in Europe before returning and reentering now with my student documents a week before my course. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, and crossing into Europe and returning (almost) immediately is so common it has the name "channel hopping".

Comment: Technically, you would not have a ‘tourist’ visa. US citizens visiting the UK for tourism purposes are allowed to enter visa-free https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism

Answer (score 1):

The rules permit you to do what you want. There's more detail in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/140274/105640)

However, bear in mind that flights are limited at present, Schengen area borders are closed to US travellers, and non-essential travel is severely restricted in Britain.

This might change before you intend to travel, but at least one EU country is talking about maintaining the border closure until September ([Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/tamarathiessen/2020/04/11/europe-borders-may-close-until-september-due-to-us-covid-19-threat/#504bbf6c5056)).

You would do well to keep your travel plans flexible, and perhaps take your holiday after your course.